# Front-end IPFS library

Tags: ipfs

I'm looking for a light IFPS library that I can include on the front-end.

I only need to save files and retrieve the hash.

Using Browserify on https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api is about 2.2mb, which seems high.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-ipfs Looks good but hasn't been updated in two years.

Answer (score 1):

...just found a good solution, only about 3kb:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-mini